# Jenkins Build Failure

Tags: ant, migration-tool, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm receiving this error when trying to run a Jenkins Job. The file configuration seems to be valid. What steps should I take to troublshoot this issue?

```
Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:com.salesforce:deploy
    Cause: The name is undefined.
    Action: Check the spelling.
    Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
    Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
    No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

    This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
    Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
            -/usr/share/ant/lib
            -/var/lib/jenkins/.ant/lib
            -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this means that your build.xml file can't find the salesforce ant jar file. Check out https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_install.htm

Comment: Thanks... I'm getting this error now Git/build.xml:24: sf:deploy doesn't support the "testLevel" attribute

Comment: I ended up downloading an updated version of the migration tool and it seems to be working. Thanks!